# Targeting data attribute & running function issue

Tags: javascript, function, getattribute

I'm trying to target different elements on the page by it's data-product, and setting a rule that if the data-product is a certain number then to run the function. But at the moment the functions runs multiple times and i'm not sure why this is.

```js
var targetProduct = document.querySelectorAll('.content[data-product]').forEach(function(el) {
  if ('1'.indexOf(el.getAttribute('data-product')) > -1) {
    addMessage();
  } else if ('2'.indexOf(el.getAttribute('data-product')) > -1) {
    addMessage();
  }
});


function addMessage() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(el) {
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p style='color: red'>Sale</p>");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="content" data-product="1">
  <p class='product'>Product 1</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="2">
  <p class='product'>Product 2</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="3">
  <p class='product'>Product 3</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="4">
  <p class='product'>Product 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: by calling `addMessage()` are you sure you want to make all products red? Or do you want to make red only particular product?

Comment: @Georgy only select items. I'm trying to target the data-product of the product. `if i have "  el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p style='color: red'>Sale</p>");" in each if statement it runs fine but when i try to add it as it's own function it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addMessage()` function is adding the `Sale` text to all elements through the `.forEach` method. You should instead pass to it the element that needs to have `.insertAdjacentHTML` done to it and then inside the function only update that one element.

Here is a working example. Note that I have combined the two if-statements into one using the [logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator.

```js
const targetProduct = document.querySelectorAll('.content[data-product]')

targetProduct.forEach(function(el) {
  const attr = el.getAttribute('data-product')
  if ('1'.indexOf(attr) > -1 || '2'.indexOf(attr) > -1) {
    addMessage(el)
  }
})

function addMessage(el) {
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<p style='color: red'>Sale</p>")
}
```

```html
<div class="content" data-product="1">
  <p class="product">Product 1</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="2">
  <p class="product">Product 2</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="3">
  <p class="product">Product 3</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="4">
  <p class="product">Product 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a label to particular item, you could use this. Does it solve your problem?

```js
var targetProduct = document.querySelectorAll('.content[data-product]').forEach(function(el) {
  if ('1'.indexOf(el.getAttribute('data-product')) > -1) {
    addMessage('1');
  } else if ('2'.indexOf(el.getAttribute('data-product')) > -1) {
    addMessage('2');
  }
});


function addMessage(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.content[data-product="' + id + '"] .product').forEach(function(el) {
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p style='color: red'>Sale</p>");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="content" data-product="1">
  <p class='product'>Product 1</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="2">
  <p class='product'>Product 2</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="3">
  <p class='product'>Product 3</p>
</div>

<div class="content" data-product="4">
  <p class='product'>Product 4</p>
</div>
```